# R function or approach for calculating a mean raster layer from a list of rasters?

Tags: r, terra

I have a list of multilayer rasters (e.g., stacks) with matching extents and layer names, and I need to average them to create a single stack retaining the appropriate layers. This can easily be achieved by manually removing each raster from the list and simply using `terra::mean(stack.1, stack.2, na.rm = T)`.

Unfortunately, I have to do this repeatedly with numerous files and need an omnibus solution. I am also aware that I can use `terra::rast()` on a list of rasters to create a single stack, and could take the mean of this object, but this approach averages all layers resulting in only a single layer, rather than a stack of averaged layers. Similarly, `lapply()` and `do.call()` are not helpful because these apply functions to each element in the list, not all elements collectively. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Code sample:

```
# Structure of stacks
stack.1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 776, 720, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.6, 0.6  (x, y)
extent      : 278110.2, 278542.2, 4752927, 4753393  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N (EPSG:32616) 
source      : pepr.2022.100.tif 
names       : preds~_temp, preds~_temp, preds~_temp, preds~vapor, preds~vapor, preds~vapor 
min values  :   -2.074884,    29.46503,    7.464921,   -118.1709,    2325.729,    984.7896 
max values  :    1.352281,    43.14127,   11.517185,    128.4751,    2929.794,   1289.9479

# Listed
stack.list <- list(stack.1, stack.2, stack.3)

# Desired result, a stack containing the same layers that have been averaged
mean(stack.1, stack.2, stack.3, na.rm =T)
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 776, 720, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.6, 0.6  (x, y)
extent      : 278110.2, 278542.2, 4752927, 4753393  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 16N (EPSG:32616) 
source(s)   : memory
names       : preds~_temp, preds~_temp, preds~_temp, preds~vapor, preds~vapor, preds~vapor 
min values  :   -1.928547,    29.14394,    5.955294,   -115.4321,    2044.692,    941.3278 
max values  :    1.215450,    38.19327,    9.235113,    127.4777,    2525.456,   1166.1364
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SpatRasterDataset and then use `terra::app`

Example data

```
r <- rast(system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra"))   
x <- list(r, r*10, r*100)
```

Solution

```
s <- sds(x)
app(s, mean)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent      : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : Cartesian (Meter) 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       :  red, green, blue 
#min values  :    0,     0,    0 
#max values  : 9435,  9435, 9435
```

"manual approach" for comparison

```
minmax(mean(r, r*10, r*100))
#     red green blue
#min    0     0    0
#max 9435  9435 9435
```

Comment: Thank you! Very concise solution too. I knew there had to be something I was missing.